# Azure Resource Syntax For Scripting

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Where can the template structures be found for each Azure Resource? If I use the ARM Template it will populate a few predefined items; however, they do not align with the fields that are in the Azure Portal.

I've attached two items (1) JSON from Azure Portal and (2) VSC Code from an ARM Template. Do you see how the Azure Portal provides more properties and how the field names (in many cases) between the documents do not aligned 1:1?

So, how can I create a script in VSC for an Azure Resource if:

1. I'm not sure what field names to use in VSC because they may not align 1:1 with the Azure Portal when I go to deploy it.
2. The VSC ARM Template doesn't provide me with the 'all-inclusive' list of properties and predefined dropdown values(in some cases).

I really hope what I am trying to get across makes sense. For instance, "sku" from the Azure Portal upload has no mentioning in the VSC ARM Template; therefore, I would have no idea to include that and no idea into what "sku" means if I had to compare that to the Azure Portal screen where you can manually create the Azure resource through the Graphical User Interface.

I've been scrolling through countless Microsoft documentations for days/weeks where it shows examples here and there but nothing that encompasses what I'm seeking.

It's like I can deploy a resource from VSC, but it won't contain all the property requirements that are required to be completed by the business.

I am new to this, so please feel free to breakdown the answers to a granular level. My ultimate goal is to "learn and understand" so I can help to empower our clients, etc.

VSC Example:[image: ARM Template from VSC]
Azure Portal Example: [image: Azure Portal View of SQL DB Syntax]

Comment: you could always use bicep, it has all the intellisense stuff

Comment: Hi , any update on this question, have you checked my answer, does my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

For sample, Please refer to the official document in this place:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-arm-template-quickstart?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftemplates%2Ftoc.json&view=azuresql#review-the-template

The definition of SKU may not be easy to find, please take a look of this official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/product-resources#sku

> The full name of SKU is 'Stock Keeping Unit', it represents a
> purchasable Stock Keeping Unit under a product.

For SKU in SQL, you can check it's structure in these places:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.database.sku?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.sku?view=azure-dotnet